# Setting an array element with a sequence (Python)

Tags: python, physics, solver

I've been trying to solve a system of equations using solve_ivp but I get an error saying:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I have been trying different things but nothing works I thought I'd share the code here and hopefully, someone can help me. Don't worry too much about the code in geta33 below it's a regularization method I'm trying to implement the problem lies in firstorder and solve_ivp.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from numpy import linalg as LA
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

G = 1
mu1=3.0616236117028484e+20
mu2=3.0616236117028484e+20

def geta33(Qf1, Qf2, dQf, m2):
    Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 = Qf1
    Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8 = Qf2
    dQ1, dQ2, dQ3, dQ4 = dQf
    q1 = Q1 ** 2 - Q2 ** 2 - Q3 ** 2 + Q4 ** 2
    q2 = 2 * Q1 * Q2 - 2 * Q3 * Q4
    q3 = 2 * Q1 * Q3 + 2 * Q2 * Q4
    q4 = Q5 ** 2 - Q6 ** 2 - Q7 ** 2 + Q8 ** 2
    q5 = 2 * Q5 * Q6 - 2 * Q7 * Q8
    q6 = 2 * Q5 * Q7 + 2 * Q6 * Q8
    qf1 = np.array([q1, q2, q3])
    qf2 = np.array([q4, q5, q6])
    norm1 = sum((qf1 - qf2) ** 2) ** 0.5
    a0 = -G * m2 * (qf1[0] - qf2[0]) / norm1 ** 3
    a1 = -G * m2 * (qf1[1] - qf2[1]) / norm1 ** 3
    a2 = -G * m2 * (qf1[2] - qf2[2]) / norm1 ** 3
    D = 4 * (Q1 ** 2 + Q2 ** 2 + Q3 ** 2 + Q4 ** 2)
    r1 = np.sqrt((q1 - mu2) ** 2 + q2 ** 2 + q3 ** 2)
    r2 = np.sqrt((q1 + mu1) ** 2 + q2 ** 2 + q3 ** 2)
    D = 4 * (Q1 ** 2 + Q2 ** 2 + Q3 ** 2 + Q4 ** 2)
    dD = 8 * (Q1 * dQ1 + Q2 * dQ2 + Q3 * dQ3 + Q4 * dQ4)
    dq1 = 2 * (Q1 * dQ1 - Q2 * dQ2 - Q3 * dQ3 + Q4 * dQ4)
    dq2 = 2 * (Q2 * dQ1 + Q1 * dQ2 - Q4 * dQ3 - Q3 * dQ4)
    dq3 = 2 * (Q3 * dQ1 + Q1 * dQ3 + Q4 * dQ2 + Q2 * dQ4)
    ddq0 = a0
    ddq1 = a1
    ddq2 = a2
    qpp0 = D ** 2 * (a0 + (dD / D ** 3) * dq1)
    qpp1 = D ** 2 * (a1 + (dD / D ** 3) * dq2)
    qpp2 = D ** 2 * (a2 + (dD / D ** 3) * dq3)
    C1 = 2 * (dQ1 * dQ1 - dQ2 * dQ2 - dQ3 * dQ3 + dQ4 * dQ4)
    C2 = 2 * (dQ2 * dQ1 + dQ1 * dQ2 - dQ4 * dQ3 - dQ3 * dQ4)
    C3 = 2 * (dQ3 * dQ1 + dQ1 * dQ3 + dQ4 * dQ2 + dQ2 * dQ4)
    C4 = 2 * (dQ4 * dQ1 - dQ3 * dQ2 + dQ2 * dQ3 - dQ1 * dQ4)
    c = np.array(
        [
            [2 * Q1, -2 * Q2, -2 * Q3, 2 * Q4],
            [2 * Q2, 2 * Q1, -2 * Q4, -2 * Q3],
            [2 * Q3, 2 * Q4, 2 * Q1, 2 * Q2],
            [2 * Q4, -2 * Q3, 2 * Q2, -2 * Q1],
        ]
    )
    b = np.array([qpp0 - C1, qpp1 - C2, qpp2 - C3, -C4])
    return [*dQf, *np.linalg.solve(c, b)]


state0 = np.array(
    [
        np.array([22.33824111, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
        np.array([0.03862643, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0]),
        np.array([0.00000000e00, -3.50534105e13, 0.00000000e00, 0.00000000e00]),
        3.0616327659574474e20,
    ]
)
me = 3.0616327659574474e20
t = 0
T = 10 ** 7
AU = 499
a = AU


def firstorder(t, state):
    pos, vel = state.reshape(2, -1)
    return [
        vel[0][0],
        vel[0][1],
        vel[0][2],
        vel[0][3],
        vel[1],
        *geta33(pos[0], pos[1], vel[0], me),
    ]


sol = solve_ivp(firstorder, [0, T], state0, first_step=1e5, atol=1e-6 * a)
```

Comment: Hi, if you execute `firstorder(0,state0)` before calling solve_ivp, you get the error: `NameError: name 'G' is not defined` at `File "script.py", line 19, in geta33`.

Comment: Hi thank you don't know why that would happen but I've added G=1 now so hopefully that wont cause any more trouble?

Comment: Then you get the same problem for `mu1` and `mu2` that are also undefined. However, the error still remains. If you refer to the documentation of sole_ivp (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), the input `state` of the function `firstorder` should be an array of the same size than it's output. This is not your case, `len(firstorder(0,state0))` is equal to `13` while `state0` is an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the problem by replacing the definition of `state0` by a 1D-array:

```
state0 = np.array([ # We define input as a 1D array
  *[ 22.33824111,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
  *[ 0.03862643, -0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
  *[  0.00000000e+00,  -3.50534105e+13,   0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
  3.0616327659574474e+20
])
```

and add a little of code in the beginning of the `firstorder` function to convert the array on your preferred format:

```
def firstorder(t, state_vec):
  state = np.array([ # We convert the 1D array to an array of arrays
    np.array(state_vec[0:4]),
    np.array(state_vec[4:8]),
    np.array(state_vec[8:12]),
    state_vec[12]
  ])
  pos, vel = state.reshape(2,-1)
  return [vel[0][0],vel[0][1],vel[0][2],vel[0][3],vel[1], *geta33(pos[0],pos[1],vel[0],me)]
```

The code is running but you are now encountering overflow problems which is another issue in my opinion. You should work on your program to avoid using very big numbers like `3.0e+20` and also avoid taking the cubic power of such big numbers. Here is the output:

```
% python3 script.py
script.py:23: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  a0=-G*m2*(qf1[0]-qf2[0])/norm1**3
script.py:24: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  a1=-G*m2*(qf1[1]-qf2[1])/norm1**3
script.py:25: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  a2=-G*m2*(qf1[2]-qf2[2])/norm1**3
script.py:37: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  qpp0=D**2*(a0+(dD/D**3)*dq1)
script.py:38: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  qpp1=D**2*(a1+(dD/D**3)*dq2)
script.py:39: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  qpp2=D**2*(a2+(dD/D**3)*dq3)
script.py:22: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  norm1=sum( (qf1-qf2)**2 )**0.5
script.py:27: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  r1=np.sqrt((q1-mu2)**2+q2**2+q3**2)
script.py:28: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  r2=np.sqrt((q1+mu1)**2+q2**2+q3**2)
script.py:37: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  qpp0=D**2*(a0+(dD/D**3)*dq1)
script.py:38: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  qpp1=D**2*(a1+(dD/D**3)*dq2)
script.py:39: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  qpp2=D**2*(a2+(dD/D**3)*dq3)
```

Good luck you are almost there!

Comment: Hi thank you I did manage to solve it but have issue with the overflow which I'm working on now.

Comment: @Linus Good! Also try to use existing functions for basic operations. For instance, at line 22, you can replace `norm1=sum( (qf1-qf2)**2 )**0.5` by `norm1=np.linalg.norm(qf1-qf2)` which is faster.